# [ApacheBeam RedisIO]: Expiretime does not work for PFADD write method

Tags: redis, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Basically I'm writing a pipeline that writes data into Redis using the method PFADD, that said, some keys need to have an expireTime but it seems that apachebeam 2.33 does not support that. Does anyone know how to proceed in this case?

Below an example of my code:

```
redisFlattenHourDownloadCount.apply("Writing Hour download count into Redis", RedisIO.write().withMethod(RedisIO.Write.Method.PFADD).withEndpoint(appConfiguration.redisUrl, appConfiguration.redisPort).withExpireTime(appConfiguration.redisExpireHourTimeMillis))
```

if I go deep in RedisIO, we can find this function:

```
private void writeUsingHLLCommand(KV<String, String> record, Long expireTime) {
        String key = record.getKey();
        String value = record.getValue();

        pipeline.pfadd(key, value);
      }
```

but as you can see the variable expireTime is not being used

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding a call to  `setExpireTimeWhenRequired(key, expireTime)` should suffice, similar to what's done in, e.g. `writeUsingListCommand`.  Are you comfortable creating a pull request?

Comment: I created a ticket on their Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13284

Comment: Thanks. Would you be interested in creating or reviewing a pull request?

Comment: I'd be interested in reviewing... would you have time to create a PR?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/16052

Comment: Thanks Robert! Approved